# Find out the index of a rolling function in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df with some values, and I am trying to find out the min value of a column or a rolling basis, as well as the indices of those rolling min values.

For example,

```
df["low"].rolling(200).min()
```

creates a series of the min "low" in a rolling 200 period.

Can anybody suggest how to get the indices for "low" of that new rolling series?

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Do you want the index of the element in the original dataframe or the new rolling series?

Comment: My example above returns the lowest low in a rolling basis. I want a series of the index of that element. (it could consist mostly of a fixed number, until a new low is found. My code displays the actual low, but I also need the index in the df of that low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'low': np.random.randint(0,100,20)})

window_size = 4
df['min'] = df['low'].rolling(window_size).min()
df['min_idx'] = (df['low'].rolling(window_size).apply(np.argmin) + df.index - window_size + 1).astype('Int64')
```

Result:

```
    low   min  min_idx
0    44   NaN     <NA>
1    47   NaN     <NA>
2    64   NaN     <NA>
3    67  44.0        0
4    67  47.0        1
5     9   9.0        5
6    83   9.0        5
7    21   9.0        5
8    36   9.0        5
9    87  21.0        7
10   70  21.0        7
11   88  36.0        8
12   88  70.0       10
13   12  12.0       13
14   58  12.0       13
15   65  12.0       13
16   39  12.0       13
17   87  39.0       16
18   46  39.0       16
19   88  39.0       16
```

---

The above works for a range index from `0` to `len(df)-1`. If you have any other index it becomes a bit more involved:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'low': np.random.randint(0,100,20)})
df.index = np.random.permutation(20)

window_size = 4
df['min'] = df['low'].rolling(window_size).min()
min_idx = df.index[(df['low'].rolling(window_size).apply(np.argmin) + pd.RangeIndex(len(df)) - window_size + 1)[window_size-1:].astype(int)]
df['min_idx'] = [np.nan]*(window_size - 1) + min_idx.tolist()
df['min_idx'] = df['min_idx'].astype('Int64')
```

Result:

```
    low   min  min_idx
6    44   NaN     <NA>
14   47   NaN     <NA>
16   64   NaN     <NA>
10   67  44.0        6
7    67  47.0       14
1     9   9.0        1
15   83   9.0        1
11   21   9.0        1
2    36   9.0        1
12   87  21.0       11
18   70  21.0       11
19   88  36.0        2
0    88  70.0       18
3    12  12.0        3
4    58  12.0        3
9    65  12.0        3
8    39  12.0        3
13   87  39.0        8
5    46  39.0        8
17   88  39.0        8
```

Comment: Help a lot! thx